# Helical wire antenna normal mode or axis mode?

Tags: rf, antenna, transceiver

I have bought theses two RF-transceiver CC1101 module from e-bay(image below), and I want to know if it is a helical antenna in normal mode or in an axis mode.

The specification doesn't say anything about it.

Can someone help me to detirmne this?

[image]

Comment: Helical antenna it is directional antenna and combined with reflector and have some directional gain. So this is not a helical antenna. It is a spring or coil antenna (λ/2 may be) with an omnidirectional radiation pattern, with 0dBd or 2.15dBi gain

Answer (score 2):

With this kind of helix, the energy is radiated in all directions (mostly) perpendicular to the axis of the helix.

There is a different kind of helical antenna that's sometimes used to produce circularly-polarized signals, but for that to work, the dimensions of the helix must be comparable to the wavelength in quesion. Specifically, the circumference of the helix needs to be λ and the turn spacing needs to be λ/4. Such an antenna radiates its energy along the axis of the helix, in the direction away from the feed point.